Need query to get the result like below from input value and apply status based on the non zero amounts to future months
Query to get the result like below from input value and apply status based on the non zero amounts to future months.
First 3 months from non zero value is Newly Inactive
Then 3 months to 6 months from non zero value is Inactive
Then 6 months or more months from non zero value is Frozen
Input value:



Month
Value




01-11-2019
10


01-12-2019
0


01-01-2020
0


01-02-2020
0


01-03-2020
0


01-04-2020
0


01-05-2020
0


01-06-2020
0


01-07-2020
0


01-08-2020
0


01-09-2020
0


01-10-2020
0


01-11-2020
0


01-12-2020
0



Output value:



Month
Value
Status




01-11-2019
10
Active


01-12-2019
0
Newly Inactive


01-01-2020
0
Newly Inactive


01-02-2020
0
Newly Inactive


01-03-2020
0
Inactive


01-04-2020
0
Inactive


01-05-2020
0
Inactive


01-06-2020
0
Inactive


01-07-2020
0
Inactive


01-08-2020
0
Inactive


01-09-2020
0
Frozen


01-10-2020
0
Frozen


01-11-2020
0
Frozen


01-12-2020
0
Frozen



stg_status AS (
    SELECT 
        month,
        value,
        CASE 
            WHEN total_amount > 0 THEN 'Active'
            WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(month, LAG(month) OVER (ORDER BY MONTH)) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Freshly Inactive'
            WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(month, LAG(month) OVER (ORDER BY month)) BETWEEN 4 AND 12 THEN 'Inactive'
            WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(month, LAG(month) OVER (ORDER BY month))>12 THEN 'Frozen'
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS status
    FROM 
        my_table
)
SELECT 
    month,
    value,
    status
FROM 
    stg_status
ORDER BY 
    month;


LAG isn't working for you because it is always giving you the previous month instead of the last month that had a value over 0. This CTE includes a step to capture the last active month (month with a value greater than 0).
with my_table(month, value) as (
  select * from values
    ('2019-11-01'::date, 10),
    ('2019-12-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-01-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-02-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-03-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-04-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-05-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-06-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-07-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-08-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-09-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-10-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-11-01'::date, 0),
    ('2020-12-01'::date, 0)
),
tmax as (
  select max(month) as last_active from my_table where value > 0
),
stg_status AS (
    SELECT 
        month,
        value,
        CASE 
            WHEN value > 0 THEN 'Active'
            WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(month, last_active) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Freshly Inactive'
            WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(month, last_active) BETWEEN 4 AND 12 THEN 'Inactive'
            WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(month, last_active) > 12 THEN 'Frozen'
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS status
    FROM 
        my_table, tmax
)
SELECT 
    month,
    value,
    status
FROM 
    stg_status
ORDER BY 
    month;

